# Designing database for a simple multilingual CMS

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a simple CMS I am trying to build myself but I am stuck at designing the structure of the database.

I have 3 tables in my database : content, images, seo (and I will have a blog laterly)

My question is that about seo table. I am trying to use seo table for both pages and images (for alt tags)

However I only need seo title and seo description for pages and seo title for images. Is it better to separate it to 2 tables like images_seo and page_seo ? I will have about 10 pages (x3 languages) but more than 200 pictures. What is the proper way to do it?

My **content** table looks like:

```
----------------------------------------------------
ID | content_id | page_id | lang_code | content_text
```

**images** table :

```
-------------------------
ID | page_id | image_name
```

My **seo** tables looks like that at the moment

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID | page_id | image_id | lang_code | type  | page_title | seo_title  | seo_desc
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 |    1    |     1    |     en    | image |            | test image |
 2 |    1    |          |     fr    | page  | Homepage   | test page  | page seo desc
```

Comment: Instead of separating your content and images tables - you could do one table and add a type column which would simplify the structure

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem another way on my seo content module. Each content page have files with pictures and text with content in language. When content is edit in WYSIWYG Editor link to images inserted in text. It's because same image can be used in different languages with different alt tags or image also must be translated if contain text. 
So my structure is: content->({content in language},{pictures})